# WindowsPhone | Can VoiceCommand lead to a method call instead Navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, voice-recognition

I have `VoiceCommand` almost like in this example:

```
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.0">
    <CommandSet xml:lang="en-US">
        <CommandPrefix>Contoso Rodeo</CommandPrefix>
        <Example> play a new game </Example>

        <Command Name="PlayUnknownLevel">
            <Example> replay level two </Example>
            <ListenFor> [and] replay level {*} </ListenFor>
            <Feedback> Unknown level; going to level selection... </Feedback>
            <Navigate Target="LevelSelect.xaml" />
        </Command>

        ...

    </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

When `VoiceCommand` has been recognized I need to call some method

Question is: Can `VoiceCommand` lead to a method call instead Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke a method by handling the OnNavigatedTo() of the Navigate Target.

There's a good example of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: But I don't want to navigate. I want to stay on current page